# How to get many rolling window slices in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have the following numpy array:

```
[[[1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3]],
 [[4], [5], [6], [4], [5], [6]],
 [[7], [8], [9], [7], [8], [9]]]
```

And I want each of the elements in the last dimension, `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]` etc. to be concatenate with the following `n` arrays in the second dimension. In case of overflow, elements can be filled with 0. For example, for `n = 2`:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 0], [3, 0, 0]],
 [[4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 4], [6, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 0], [6, 0, 0]],
 [[7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 7], [9, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 0], [9, 0, 0]]]
```

I want to do this with the built in numpy functions for good performance and also want to do it in reverse i.e., a shift of `n = -2` is fair game. How to do this?

For `n = -2`:

```
[[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[0, 0, 4], [0, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 4], [6, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]],
 [[0, 0, 7], [0, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 7], [9, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]]
```

For `n = 3`

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0], [2, 3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[4, 5, 6, 4], [5, 6, 4, 5], [6, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 0], [5, 6, 0, 0], [6, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[7, 8, 9, 7], [8, 9, 7, 8], [9, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 0], [8, 9, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

If the current shape of the array is `(height, width, 1)`, after the operation, the shape will be `(height, width, abs(n) + 1)`.

How to generalize this so that the numbers 1, 2, 3 etc. can themselves be numpy arrays?

Comment: The pattern isn't obvious

Comment: how does the n=-2 output look like?

Comment: @hpaulj. Example for n = 3 as well. Look at the following n of each of the [x]. Suppose we have [x] [y] [z] and n = 2, then we get [x y z]. If we have [x] [y] [z] [a] and n = 3, we get [x y z a].

Comment: @Ehsan, the edit contains n=-2

Comment: Something is missing for `n=-2`? What is the pattern? Please show a loop-based implementation, or at least spell out the rules clearly. Also, please clearly specify the shapes you are expecting. What you have here is a notation that likely makes sense to you, but is not python code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist there were some errors in the patterns, which are now corrected.

Comment: I think more people would understand if you didn't reuse the numbers more than once.

Comment: Your shape seems to be  `(h, w, abs(n) + 1)`.

Comment: Can you please put commas into the arrays so I can copy them as code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

if n>=0:
  a = np.pad(a.reshape(*a.shape[:-1]),((0,0),(0,n)))
else:
  n *= -1
  a = np.pad(a.reshape(*a.shape[:-1]),((0,0),(n,0)))

b = view_as_windows(a,(1,n+1))
b = b.reshape(*b.shape[:-2]+(n+1,))
```

`a` is your input array and `b` is your output:

`n=2`:

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [2 3 1]
  [3 1 2]
  [1 2 3]
  [2 3 0]
  [3 0 0]]

 [[4 5 6]
  [5 6 4]
  [6 4 5]
  [4 5 6]
  [5 6 0]
  [6 0 0]]

 [[7 8 9]
  [8 9 7]
  [9 7 8]
  [7 8 9]
  [8 9 0]
  [9 0 0]]]
```

`n=-2`:

```
[[[0 0 1]
  [0 1 2]
  [1 2 3]
  [2 3 1]
  [3 1 2]
  [1 2 3]]

 [[0 0 4]
  [0 4 5]
  [4 5 6]
  [5 6 4]
  [6 4 5]
  [4 5 6]]

 [[0 0 7]
  [0 7 8]
  [7 8 9]
  [8 9 7]
  [9 7 8]
  [7 8 9]]]
```

**Explanation**:

- `np.pad(a.reshape(*a.shape[:-1]),((0,0),(0,n)))` pads enough zeros to the right side of array for overflow of windows (similarly padding left side for negative `n`)
- `view_as_windows(a,(1,n+1))` creates windows of shape `(1,n+1)` from the array as desired by the question.
- `b.reshape(*b.shape[:-2]+(n+1,))` gets rid of the extra dimension of length 1 created by `(1,n+1)`-shaped windows and reshape `b` to desired shape. Note the argument `*b.shape[:-2]+(n+1,)` is simply concatenation of two tuples to create a single tuple as shape.

Comment: The line a = np.pad(a.reshape(*a.shape[:-1]),((0,0),(0,n))) gives:
TypeError: pad() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mode'

Comment: I don't know if `view_as_windows` uses `as_strided` under the hood, so I posted a full numpy solution

Comment: What if the numbers themselves are numpy arrays? Your solution doesn't seem to work in that case

Comment: @zendevil It is most likely numpy version mismatch. add `mode='constant'` to the arguments of it like: `a = np.pad(a.reshape(*a.shape[:-1]),((0,0),(0,n)),mode='constant')`. As for scalability, you need to define your questions/inputs assumptions/shapes to get the general answer you want. I assumed the shape of your array is similar to your examples.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am not sure of implementation details but I will put my money on that `view_as_windows` uses numpy `as_strided`. I always like your solutions. They are always great. Upvoted.

Comment: @Ehsan, would you please explain the answer? What's the role of the tuple that's the second arg of .reshape and what does the asterisk do?

Comment: @zendevil I added explanation to the post. Hope it helps resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a textbook application for the monster that is [`as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). One of the nice things about it is that it does not require any additional imports. The general idea is this:

1. You have an array with shape `(3, 6, 1)` and strides `(6, 1, 1) * element_size`.

   ```
   x = ...
   n = ...  # Must not be zero, but you can special-case it to return the original array
   ```
2. You want to transform this into an array that has shape `(3, 6, |n| + 1)` and therefore strides `(6 * (|n| + 1), |n| + 1, 1) * element_size`.
3. To do this, you first pad the left or the right with `|n|` zeros:

   ```
   pad = np.zeros((x.shape[0], np.abs(n), x.shape[2]))
   x_pad = np.concatenate([x, pad][::np.sign(n)], axis=1)
   ```
4. Now you can index directly into the buffer with a custom shape and strides to get the result you want. Instead of using the proper strides `(6 * (|n| + 1), |n| + 1, 1) * element_size`, we will index each repeated element directly into the same buffer of the original array, meaning that the strides will be adjusted. The middle dimension will move by one element, rather than the proper `|n| + 1`. That way, the columns can start exactly where you want them to:

   ```
   new_shape = (x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2] + np.abs(n))
   new_strides = (x_pad.strides[0], x_pad.strides[2], x_pad.strides[2])
   result = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x_pad, shape=new_shape, strides=new_strides)
   ```

There are many caveats here. The biggest thing to be aware of is that multiple array elements access the same memory. My advice is to make a proper fleshed-out copy if you plan to do anything besides just reading the data:

```
result = result.copy()
```

This will give you a buffer of the correct size rather than a crazy view into the original data with padding.

Comment: What if the numbers themselves are numpy arrays? Your solution doesn't seem to work in that case

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. You are providing a linear shift. How do you want to handle multiple shifts?

Comment: @zendevil. By the way, it's bad practice to add "edit" to your question. Just modify it to be a complete stand-alone post. We can see the edit history any time we need to.

Comment: If we have [x] [y] [z] and n = 2, then we get [x y z]. If we have [x] [y] [z] [a] and n = 3, we get [x y z a]. The point is that x y z need not be numbers but can themselves be numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this (requires numpy version 1.20.x+

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3]],
            [[4], [5], [6], [4], [5], [6]],
            [[7], [8], [9], [7], [8], [9]]])

n = 2 # your n value
nslices = n+1

# reshape into 2d array
arr = arr.reshape((3, -1)) # <-- add n zeros as padding here

# perform the slicing
slices = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, (1, nslices))
slices = slices[:, :, 0]

print(slices)
```