# How to use numpy to concatenate arrays in the following manner?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of dimension:
(1, 1, 188, 621, 32) corresponding to the (batch, depth, height, width, features) dimensions

And I want to convert this array to have the shape (1, 48, 188, 621, 32), i.e., have a depth of 48, where the rest of the arrays in the depth dimension will be the array that's (height, width + x), for x = 1 to x = 47, distance away from the current one?

In case of overflow, the array can be full of zeros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get many rolling window slices in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459142/how-to-get-many-rolling-window-slices-in-numpy) . Your example output shape does not match your claimed shape. Please specify in more detail how this is different than your previous question as the input/output look the same.

Comment: If you want to ask a question about an array with a dimension of size 32, please post an example with such an array. Perhaps reduce the size to say 5 for the example? Right now this is basically a duplicate of your previous question, to which you have *still* not selected an answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, please let me know if the question isn't clear.

Comment: Please give a concrete example. I'm having a hard time following you.

Comment: How is this any different from your previous question, except in the number of dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 48 arrays of shape  (1, 1, 188, 621, 32) then just

```
bigarr = np.concatenate([arr1, arr2, ... , arr48], axis=1)
```

will produce the (1,48, 188, 621, 32).  The concatenation part is trivial.

Now you just need to figure out how to generate the 47 added arrays from the first (at least that seems to be what you are trying to do).